# captive portal authentication theory

Tags: cryptography

I'm a little confused on how captive portal authentication works. In some implementations, after a user is authenticated with a login page, their IP and MAC address are whitelisted and allowed to connect through the gateway. Obviously this has the problem of people spoofing MAC addresses to gain access. If the portal sets up a session between itself and the client, does that mean that every piece of traffic that the client requests from the internet must go through the portal's server?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, security in a captive portal is not considered particularly important. However, there are solutions that lock a MAC to the first port to use it and disallow the use of that MAC on any additional port. Similar techniques can be used wirelessly, where the AP will refuse to pair with an additional client using the same MAC address as an existing client. This requires enterprise authentication where a unique key is negotiated for each attached device.

It's not clear to me what you mean by "the portal's server". But generally, once a MAC address is authorized and the wired port is configured or the wireless connection is established, nothing further needs to be done by the portal. The traffic for authenticated connections is just routed/NATted normally.